# Repeatable block functionlaity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop functionality for repeatable blocks within my web form, the issue being the buttons do nothing when I click them I have tested them in the console and they do work, they just dont do anything and am unsure why, been working on this for 2 days and am at a standstill, anyone who can point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

It should generate the fields contained within that field set and generate a identical empty field set, and not sure whats wrong with the plus or minus functions.

```
                   $('input, fieldset').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('data-maxOccurs') != 1){
            $(plusMinusButtons).insertAfter(this);
        }
    });
    $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').hover(function(){
                                                $(this).addClass('green');
                                              },
                                    function(){
                                                $(this).removeClass('green');
                                              }
                                    );
    $('.glyphicon-minus-sign').hover(function(){
                                                $(this).addClass('red');
                                               },
                                     function(){
                                                $(this).removeClass('red');
                                               }
                                    );
    $('body').on("click", '.glyphicon-plus-sign', function (){
                                                        prevInput = $(this).prev('input');
                                                        count = $(prevInput).attr('data-count');
                                                        countIncremented = count++;
                                                        br = '<br/><br/>';
                                                        inputElement = '<input type="'+$(prevInput).attr("type")+'" name="'+$(prevInput).attr("name")+countIncremented+'" data-count="'+countIncremented+'"/>';
                                                        $(br + inputElement + plusMinusButtons).insertAfter('.'+$(prevInput).attr("name")+':last');
                                                    }
                                );
    $('body').on("click", '.glyphicon-minus-sign', function (){
                                                        prevInput = $(this).prev('input');
                                                        $(this).remove(prevInput).remove(this);
                                                    }
                                );
    $("button").click(function(){
        console.log("here");
        x=$('#form').serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
          console.log(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the JSfiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeSa8/20/)

Comment: You Fiddle looks wrong. perhaps try formatting the HTML better to get the correct quotes around some of your attributes.

Comment: I think the issue is now resolved, let me know if its ok

Comment: Nope, `<fieldset data-maxOccurs="1" data-minOccurs="0" data-name="billingAccount" data-nillable="nulldata-value=" &lt;b&gt; ">` still looks wrong to me.

Comment: Its seems fine for me

Comment: There are an odd number of quotes in the markup of this fieldset tag. How can that be correct? It might work if the example code is not dependant on the specific attributes but it's still incorrect and possibly masking other errors or introduce other bugs.

Comment: Fiddle Issue Now resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code Used in order to duplicate the field set.

```
$('body').on("click ", '.glyphicon-plus-sign', function() {
                        console.log("here ");
                        prevInput = $(this);
                        count = $(prevInput).attr('data-count=')||0;
                        countIncremented = count++;
                        br = '<br/><br/>';


                        $($(this).parent()).clone().insertAfter($(this).parent());
```